# How do I implement the VBA module to copy filtered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I need to implement a VBA Macro that copies data from one excel worksheet and puts certain column into another one.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

'Method 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")

'Method 2
'Copy the data
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("E1").Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This wont work for new sheets named for example Sheet 3 neither will it run effectively for filtered data. I need a code that can copy the filtered data and paste certain column into another worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

In order to just copy visible cells in a filtered range, you need to specify that that is what you try to do. For instance:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                 Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")
```

Some good examples of how to use autofilter in VBA-code [can, among other places, be found here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson20.htm).

I can see no reason why this shouldn't work when you refer to other sheets, except for your use of `Activate` and `Select` maybe cancelling the copy-action at some point. Any reason you do it that way instead of how I outline it above, with a specified target range specified when you do the copying? I see it's how you do it in your first example, which I assume work.